# Post data to another server apache2(httpd) custom module

Tags: apache, apache2.4, apache-modules

I am creating an apache2(httpd) custom module ,My custom module collect params on page load  I need to make a post data request to third party server and based on response I got .
Is their any utility or which I can use to connect with third party server.

Comment: not sure if you mean just modules or some lower level function inside httpd programming. As for modules I can point you to [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html)

Comment: I had created a custom module which takes our all the http params from the request on page load , now I have send these params in form of json to another server for verification once I recieved a response I have to use this making some decision .

Comment: Can I use mod proxy inside the custom handler (hook) which I have created.

Answer (score 0):

There are no built-in ways. But you have a few options:

- Implement a basic HTTP client via APR's socket APIs.
- Implement a basic
  HTTP client via a mix of httpd and APR APIs. An example of this is in mod_proxy_hcheck.c in 2.4.x and trunk.
- Embed something like libcurl in your module